# Showing that Area of A Double Integral over A Circle Is Greater than A Value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how to solve this problem. The question is this:

Let $D$ be the region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ enclosed by the circle with equation $(x-4)^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1/16$.

Show that:
$$ \frac{3\pi}{8} \le \iint_D (xy+\frac{8}{x}+\frac{1}{y})\,dA$$

Assume that the global minimum of the integrand does not occur on the boundary of D.

Comment: Did you forget to write something after "Show that:"?

Comment: Fixed: added 3pi/8 <= . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Since all points $(x,y)$ that lie in $D$ have a positive $x$ and $y$ value, by the AM-GM inequality we have:

$$\frac{\left(xy+\frac{8}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \right) }{3} \geq \left(xy \cdot \frac{8}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{y}\right)^{1/3}$$

So, what does that say about the integrand in the region $D$?

Comment: Wow! The coincidence of the bound established by this solution with $3\pi/8$ is uncanny. Ahmed, how could you tell the AM-GM inequality was so innate to the problem?

Comment: AM-GM is often a quick way to find minimums. I sense that finding the minimum of the integrand is a good way to start. Since I can see cancellation when multiplying the terms in the integrand, AM-GM seems promising.